# How to select an entire photo ("select all") in icloud photos

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

Command-A is not working to select an entire photo. I am needing to do a manual region screenshot. Why is that? Is there an alternative?

For the following Command-A does not work: a subsequent Command-V into MSWord or Command-N into Preview do nothing. But a partial screenshot does work for both of those.

[image]

Comment: Let me get this straigt: You are trying to insert an image that is stored on iCloud to MS Word? Why not download the image or simply drag n drop?

Comment: downloading the image and then uploading  to Preview  is unwieldy. I will try to see if Drag and Drop works here.  Update: Drag and Drop does not work (from the icloud website on Chrome)

Comment: Are you on a Mac? Then you could use the photos app. Further, why do you wnat to *upload to Preview*? If I download the image from iCloud (one click) I can directly drag an drop the image from my downloads folder (which is on my dock) into the opened MS Word document (another click). This is *much* faster than a screenshot...

Comment: @X_841   I'm not following completely: _Preview_ is where I'm doing the work. Are you suggesting a two step process: to drag first to Word and then from Word to Preview?

Comment: Something in your question doesnt add up. You say you want to insert it into MS word in your question. Opening in preview is trivial, you download and double click on the image in your downloads folder

Comment: As mentioned "downloading the image and then uploading to Preview is unwieldy".  You say it's trivial - but it's extra steps that take time .  I am aware of ability to go to double click from Finder, but am looking for a direct method without two hops. Is it the answer then that is not possible from icloud?